# Remove words made up of repetitive letters

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-processing

I have a dataframe column that contains text data. It has few words entirely made up of with repetitive letters and few others having repetitive letters partially. I want to remove words made up of entirely repetitive letters and just keep the first occurrence of the letter in other case (if the count of the repetitive letter is more than 2) in the dataframe column. How to do this? For example if my dataframe has words like-

```
id   text
1     aaaa
2     bb
3     wwwwwwww
4     helloooo
5     see youuuu
```

The output should be-

```
id   text
1     
2     
3    
4    hello
5    see you
```

Comment: It is necessary to make a new list with stopwords? I do not understand what to you want to do with the dataframe.

Comment: @JacobFuchs.....It is not necessary to make a new list with stopwords. I just thought one way to do this could be that. I want to remove all "words" that are entirely made up of same repetitive "letter" from a dataframe column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be particularly elegant, and might not be very fast, but it works. I hope it's good enough for your needs.

You generate a function that sorts the string based on your needs, and then use pandas mapping to apply it to all your elements, so:

```
def clean(string):
    if (len(string)==0):
        return ''
    if (set(string) == set(string[0])):
        return ''    
    prev = None
    letters = [l for l in string]
    counter = 1
    new = []
    for l in letters:
        if l==prev:
            counter+=1
        else:
            if (counter==2):
                new.append(prev)
            counter=1
            new.append(l)
            prev = l
    return ''.join(new)
```

and then you can do:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].fillna('').map(clean)
```

Briefly, you first check whether the whole string in one letter (set will only keep unique elements). Then you start iterating over all the letters, skipping repeats but keeping count of the repeated letters. Finally, when a repeat sequence is done you add one more copy only if the number of repeats was exactly 2.

I tested this and got expected results, but if you do encounter a problem with some case I didn't think of checking, please let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: You probably have empty cells, I'll add a condition that checks that, let me know if you still get a warning